# Laravel Blade @section Not Displaying

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-blade

I have this blade page called "home.blade.php"

**home.blade.php**

```
<doctype html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{$title}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- some other html here -->
      @section('content')
      @show
   </body>
</html>
```

And I also have a file "content.blade.php"

**content.blade.php**

```
@extends('home')

@section('content')
   <p>Page content goes here</p>
@endsection
```

When I load the page on my browser though, the content in @section('content') does not display. When I check the source, it is not being output -- the line

```
<p>Page content goes here</p>
```

is not in the source code.

I don't know if it's relevant, but here is the route for this page and controller code.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', 'Controller@show')->name("home");
```

**Controller code**

```
public function show()
{
    return view("home", ['title' => "My Home"]);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is because content is in content.blade.php file and not in home.blade.php, Try loading content.blade.php view and you'll see the the text

Answer (score 1):

Updated: I have just checked again, you should load `content` view, instead of `home` layout.

I think you must define `@yield` instead of `@section` in your `home.layout.blade`

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{$title}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- some other html here -->
      @yield('content')
   </body>
</html>
```

You can read more from [Laravel Template Inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#template-inheritance)

Comment: Opps, I have just checked again. I think in your `show()` action from your controller, you have to load `content` view instead of `home` view.

Comment: Yah! got it @haidang

Comment: you should call the 'content' not the home.blade.php

Answer (score -1):

Why not try using @yield,

```
@yield('content')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Hope this helps :)